# SQLITE Studio - How do I swap two values in a column without changing the other values?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I have a table, named EMPLOYEE. I tried to swap values "8523" with "3446" using code:

EMPLOYEE

| SSN |
| --- |
| 8523 |
| 1234 |
| 3446 |
| 9321 |
| 5843 |

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET SSN = CASE
WHEN SSN = '8523' THEN '3446'
WHEN SSN = '3446' THEN '8523'
ELSE != '8523' AND '3446'
END
```

When I did this, the values swapped as I intended but all values other than 3446 and 8523 changed to '1'. How do I alter the code so that it leave everything else unchanged?

Comment: just replace the current(`ELSE != '8523' AND '3446'`) with `ELSE ssn`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ELSE != '8523' AND '3446'` which is syntactically wrong and unnecessary and add a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET SSN = CASE SSN
  WHEN '8523' THEN '3446'
  WHEN '3446' THEN '8523'
END
WHERE SSN IN ('8523', '3446')
```